# PyQt5 on Pycharm, Modules not used

Tags: python, pyqt, pycharm, pyqt4, pyqt5

working on writing a Python script to scrape a webpage after it has run its JavaScript. I realized I needed the JS to run because using the Requests wasn't returning any data. I found what seemed to be my solution [here](https://impythonist.wordpress.com/2015/01/06/ultimate-guide-for-scraping-javascript-rendered-web-pages/comment-page-1/#comment-3372) but I am having some problems still.

First of all that tutorial uses PyQt4, I have installed and tried multiple versions of PyQt 4 and 5 from the project interpreter and still can't find a solution. Here is the relevant code:

```
import PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets
import PyQt5.QtCore
import PyQt5.QtWebEngine
import PyQt5.QtWebEngineCore


class Render(QWebpage):
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        QWebPage.__init__(self)
        self.loadFinished.connect(self._loadFinished)
        self.mainFrame().load(QUrl(url))
        self.app.exec_()

    def _load_finished(self, result):
        self.frame = self.mainFrame()
        self.app.quit()
```

The QWebpage, QApplication, and QUrl calls all have 'Unresolved Reference' errors, the four PyQt5 import statements also all have 'Unused Import Statement' indications. I have tried for several hours to resolve these issues, uninstalling and reinstalling PyQt several times and searching the internet

Any advice would be awesome, Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your imports are incorrect, in python there are many ways to do it: in your case you could be like this:

1.`from package import class`

---

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtWebKitWidgets import QWebPage
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication


# Take this class for granted.Just use result of rendering.
class Render(QWebPage):
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        QWebPage.__init__(self)
        self.loadFinished.connect(self._loadFinished)
        self.mainFrame().load(QUrl(url))
        self.app.exec_()

    def _loadFinished(self, result):
        self.frame = self.mainFrame()
        self.app.quit()


url = 'http://pycoders.com/archive/'
r = Render(url)
result = r.frame.toHtml()
print(result)
```

2. `import package`, then you should use each element as `package.class`:

---

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWebKitWidgets, QtCore, QtWidgets


class Render(QtWebKitWidgets.QWebPage):
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
        QtWebKitWidgets.QWebPage.__init__(self)
        self.loadFinished.connect(self._loadFinished)
        self.mainFrame().load(QtCore.QUrl(url))
        self.app.exec_()

    def _loadFinished(self, result):
        self.frame = self.mainFrame()
        self.app.quit()


url = 'http://pycoders.com/archive/'
r = Render(url)
result = r.frame.toHtml()
print(result)
```

If you are using pycharm there is a very simple way that pycharm imports the packages correctly for you, for this you must place the dot above the word that generates the error and execute `Ctrl+M`

*Note:If you are using windows you will not be able to use these modules since Qt and therefore PyQt, use chromium, and it seems that they have a problem with Windows.*

Comment: This is a great answer! Thanks for your help with my imports. I'm new to Python from Java so this helped a ton. One more question though, I noticed the QtWebKitWidgets import but I get and error when calling it with the QWebPage, Pycharm says it can't find the reference. I tried QtWebEngine and QtWebEngineCore to replace it but I can't seem to fix it. Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like QWebPage was removed in the 5.6 release of PyQt5, I have v5.8.2 and Pycharm can only go back to 5.6. Im looking for solutions now, any suggestions would be great!

Comment: The code that I show you I have tested from the version of pyqt 5.7 forward.

Comment: what is your OS?

Comment: If you are using windows you will not be able to use these modules since Qt and therefore PyQt, use chromium, and it seems that they have a problem with Windows.

Comment: I think you're right, Windows 10. Can I still use PyQt or can you help me suggest an alternative?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? I think my post already answered your answer, please mark it as correct to continue helping you.

Comment: So your solution has worked for the most part so I marked it correct. Currently the QtWebkitWidgets is still highlighted as an "Unresolved Reference". In addition QApplication and QUrl are also highlighted and are marked "cannot find reference"

Comment: From what you have said it looks like Windows is incompatible with Qt and PyQt> I need to scrape data from a webpage after running the JavaScript, any suggestions?

Comment: It is not that PyQt or Qt are incompatible with windows, that particular module has problems, if you want to do scrapy to a page I recommend using selenium.

Comment: Started using Selenium, working exactly how I want it. Thanks for all the advice!!